# Numpy eigenvector convention changes weirdly

Tags: python, numpy, eigenvector

Okay, so I have two 36x36 matrices that are *very* similar and I need to calculate the 18th eigenvector. Of course, the eigenvector convention can be a bit arbitrary for such large matrices and high eigenvectors BUT assuming the eigenvalues are non-degenerate, they should only be distinct up to a phase, right? Well that is not the case here.

First matrix: https://shrib.com/?v=nc#Pronghorn5ke1Wa6

Second matrix: https://shrib.com/?v=nc#KirkSDikDik7rMXOA9

To demonstrate how close,

```
LA.norm(first-second)
```

gives 1.615464552286151e-11.

Also, the phase offset between the 18th eigenvector of each

```
eigvec1 = LA.eigh(first)[1][:, 18]
eigvec2 = LA.eigh(second)[1][:, 18]
eigvec1/eigvec2
```

gives

```
[-0.09638687-0.j        , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
        0.59816461-0.06896481j, -0.04320863-0.02599621j,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,  0.42297316+0.41475341j,
       -0.0985544 -0.00545411j, -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
        1.2554442 +0.67027035j, -0.8480686 -0.32419582j,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j , -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,
       -0.95358982-0.3011087j ,  0.63874412+0.28189543j]
```

As I said, there seems to generally be a phase offset with a stark exception of some specific points and I am not sure why. I really need to calculate derivatives of matrix eigenvectors but the sign convention is a real problem here if it changes in such a weird way. I can correct for a constant phase but I am not even sure what it is doing here.

Comment: Don't post off-site looks to materials relevant to the question.

Comment: Oh okay I just didn’t know how else to give the data

Comment: Paste it in so we can copy it into an editor?

Comment: It says too many characters

Comment: Fair enough. I guess you don't have much choice then.